# Best practice Git

Tags: git, commit, pull-request

I want to understand the "best" way to handle the following common scenario in a GIT world.
My Scrum Sprint has just started and I start working on my User Story.

For that User Story, I have to implement a new class ("FakeClassA") and expose 10 independent service method not related to each other. For example:

```
public class FakeClassA
{
   public static firstMethod()
   {
      System.debug('Hey firstMethod');
   }
   ...

   public static tenthMethod()
   {
      System.debug('Hey tenthMethod');
   }
}                                                  

public class FakeClassA_Test
{
   public static void firstMethod_Test()
   {
      System.debug('Hey firstMethod');
   }
   ...

   public static void tenthMethod_Test()
   {
      System.debug('Hey tenthMethod');
   }
}
```

This development will take the entire Sprint but I want to avoid waiting the last day to create a Pull Request with all the code developed since I would make the code review easily and smoothly.

How can I handle this process in a correct way?

I know I should commit each piece of code when it is ready and tested but what does it mean? One commit for the firstMethod and the related Unit Test, another commit for the secondMethod and the related Unit Test, etc.
But what about the Pull Request?
Should I open a Pull Request after each independent commit?
Should I reuse the same branch (and the same Pull Request) even if it is already merged?

I hope my point is clear.

Thanks

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not a programming question. Try Software Engineering Stack Exchange: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

My first impression is that your story is too big. You have TEN different endpoints you have to implement, and you want to test the crap out of each endpoint? That's a few different stories. Try to break it up into a few different chunks. Most of the people on my team dread reviewing huge Pull Requests, so we try to keep the changes small.

If that's not possible, do it all in one PR. That sucks if you did something the rest of the team hates (because you'll have to change a lot), but at least they won't get pestered to death by one little change here and there. It's best to submit it *all* in one PR, make all your changes, then commit it again.

But like I said originally, you really should look at breaking it up into smaller stories instead.

Your inclination to not wait until the last day of the sprint is a good one. Submit it early so:

- People will have a chance to review it
- You'll have time to make any requested changes